# Which locator should I use for Click Button when Id is not static?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am new at Selenium Java. Using Facebook example, I tried to write button click function using eclipse. For "Create New Account" button I tried using find element by id but it was not working because id is not static. Then I tried find element by class but an error occurred that compound class could not be used.
I have tried XPath but it is also not working. What web element can I use to locate this button?

[image: Inspect element on Create an account button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS Selector:

```java
a[data-testid="open-registration-form-button"]
```

or this XPath

```java
//a[@data-testid="open-registration-form-button"]
```